# How to determine the peak of the dielectric function represent an exciton?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, dielectric

I am reading a paper about exciton-induced dielectric function peak, but I am not sure how could I determine the peak of dielectric function represent an exciton?
The original paper is on [Nature Commuinication](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-017-00016-6),
The following screenshot is the [Fig.6](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-017-00016-6/figures/6) of the original paper.

[image]

Here is the original description:

> The long-lived feature at 3.88 eV corresponds to the a-axis exciton
> band, while the weaker shoulder at 4.35 eV is due to the c-axis
> exciton.
> The quasiparticle indirect gap E ind = 3.46 eV is indicated by a
> dashed grey vertical line; the direct gaps E dir = 3.92 eV (at the Γ
> point) for E ⊥ c and E dir = 4.40 eV (coincident with the onset of the
> RPA-GW) for E ǁ c are indicated by dashed black vertical lines in
> panel a and b, respectively

> The energy, shape and reciprocal space contributions for peak II
> highlights its bulk-resonance character, most evident as its offset
> coincides with the RPA-GW absorption rise. On the other hand, we found
> that exciton III for E k c (at 4.28 eV) is of a more complex nature,
> with a mixed contribution of bound excitons and delocalized resonant
> transitions. The former have the dominant character and the
> contributing transitions are found throughout the BZ, while the main
> contribution for the latter is concentrated in few points close to the
> Γ-Z line in the region around Z. The energy and shape of exciton III
> confirm the analysis of a mixed bulk resonance and localized
> character, as the continuum onset in RPA-GW appears to undergo an
> intensity enhancement. The mixed bulk-localized nature makes it less
> straightforward to estimate its EB. Assuming the RPA-GW onset at 4.40
> eV for E k c as the reference energy for evaluating EB, we estimate EB
> ∼150 meV.

My questions are:

1. I can accept that peak I is because of an exciton, which is a little bit lower than the bandgap, but what about peak II and peak III? Is it possible to have an excition energy level higher than the bandgap?
2. How could I determine that the peak on the above figure represents an exciton absorption instead of something else?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it is always possible to have exciton energy level higher than the bandgap. They are called resonant excitons. In the old language of solid-state physics, they were called critical points. Many-body perturbation theory calculations have now become more precise in providing information on the origin of these peaks. If you were to remove the Coulomb interactions, those peaks would disappear.
2. The figure you posted shows advanced computational calculations at the Bethe-Salpeter level. If those calculations capture the feature, there is not much chance that the feature is something else. Also, the energy is too high for the feature to have other origins. It makes sense those are exciton states.